# Does bitcoin give users credit/debit card. If yes, how do you request the card

Tags: client, development

I am a new user at bitcoin so things are a little difficult for me since the website isn't specific. I wanted to know how to request a credit or debit card from bitcoin(that's if it is possible). I also have a little trouble on the site while trying to enter my full residential address.

Comment: Can you list which site?

Comment: You should probably take a look at [an introduction to bitcoin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P_NHBH4OhXo) first. There is generally no need to state any personal information about you to use bitcoin and credit cards aren't needed. If you use such a service, stating which one you use is necessary for anyone to help you.

Comment: "the website" sounds scary. Please make sure you get your information from bitcoin.org , not from scam sites like bitcoin.com. To answer your question: bitcoin will definitely not give you a credit/debit card because"bitcoin" is not an entity. However some companies might provide cards that handle bitcoin accounts..

Answer (score 1):

Check [Bitcoin Debit Card Comparison](https://cointelegraph.com/news/6-cards-battle-for-bitcoin-supremacy-bitcoin-debit-card-comparison-test)